# Working with stringtokenizers and numbers

Tags: java, string, token

> Using the second StringTokenizer constructor, write a method that
>   returns either the first or second token in the input string based on
>   the token argument. You will need to set custom delimiters which are
>   enclosed in a string but not separated by commas.

okay, so this is what i have so far..... i need help making the code so that it returns either the first or the second token depending on the users input.... right now i only know how to return either the first or the second token. ive tried making a while or and if statement but it always says i cant convert int to string, ive even tried type casting but it wouldnt let me do that either.... **what can i do to make it return whichever token the user inputs?**

```
String parseEqn_p2(String input, int token) {
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, "+-/*%");

        String first = st.nextToken();
      String second = st.nextToken();

      return first ;
```

Comment: _"it always says i cant convert int to string,"_ - Use `String.valueOf(int)`

Answer (score 0):

> *""it always says i cant convert int to string,"* - Use `String.valueOf(int)`

You probably want something like this

```
if (first.eqauls(String.valueOf(token)) {
    return first;
} else if (...)  {

}
return null; // if not found
...
```

**Note** : you may also need to `.trim()` the token, depending on what the input is. If there are spaces, the tokenizer won't exclude them, so you would need to call .`trim()` on the String first before trying to compare. like

```
String first = st.nextToken().trim();
```

Also, it looks like you may want to use a character class, because what you're doing is looking using a single delimiter of *all* the characters, which isn't what you want. Try this instead

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, "[+-/*%]");
```

---

In for any case you wanted the method to return an `int`, then you would need to parse the token

```
int first = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
```

---

**Also, NOTE:** Whoever gave you this assignment, ask them to read the [documentation for StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), where you'll find this excerpt

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

The following example illustrates how the String.split method can be used to break up a string into its basic tokens:

```
     String[] result = "this is a test".split("\\s");
     for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++)
         System.out.println(result[x]);
```